# Twitter API: does one need an enterprise account to filter a query with profile_country?

Tags: twitter, twitter-api-v2

According to the [documentation about location filtering](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/filtering-tweets-by-location), there is an operator `profile_country` that can be used to filter a specific country. However these operators seem to be [restricted to enterprise accounts only](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/enterprise/search-api/overview), right?

If somebody could confirm please? And is there any alternative available with an academic account, knowing that I don't want to be restricted to geo-tagged tweets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems you are correct - it appears the location-based filtering is only available on enterprise accounts.

They have a comprehensive list of features included on both the enterprise and academic API accounts. And it is listed as a feature [on the enterprise page](https://developer.twitter.com/en/products/twitter-api/academic-research/product-details#enterprise-api), but not on the [academic track](https://developer.twitter.com/en/products/twitter-api/academic-research/product-details#academic-track) page.